# Remove plus sign from phone number using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to remove a + from a phone number field. The field name is referenced below as "MessagingPlatformKey"

I am collecting a response via SMS and feeding the then matching that user to an id field in another DE (IDAMP) and then feeding the responses to SMS_Responses_Collections

How do I delete the formatted + in the IDAMP data extension?

Example I want +18881234567 fromatted as 18881234567 in the new data extension. This is my current ampscript code:

```
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]
var @myGUID
set @myGUID = GUID()
set @Id = Lookup("IDAMP", "Id", "MessagingPlatformKey", MobileNumber)
if IndexOf(@response,'yes')>0 or IndexOf(@response,'no')>0 then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

   UpsertData('SMS_Responses_Collections', 1, 'MobileNumber', MobileNumber, 'Response', @response, 'guid', @myGUID, 'Id', @Id)

]%%
```

Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
%%[ 
/*... your initial code */

/* formatted mobile number */
  set @MobileNumber = MobileNumber
  set @plusIndex = IndexOf(@MobileNumber,"+")
  if @plusIndex != 0 then
    set @formattedNumber = Substring(@MobileNumber, Add(@plusIndex, 1))
  else
    set @formattedNumber = @MobileNumber
  endif

  UpsertData('SMS_Responses_Collections', 1, 'MobileNumber', @formattedNumber, 'Response', @response, 'guid', @myGUID, 'Id', @Id)

]%%
```

In the code above, I check whether the plus character exists in the mobile number and get the rest of the mobile number from the second order if it does exist.

References:

[IndexOf](https://ampscript.guide/indexof/)

[Substring](https://ampscript.guide/substring/)